Lagrange Multiplier Optimization: using circle, what about finding min/max inside it?
Following the picture below, I understand the constraint is the equation of a circle, where $g(x,y) = 0$ on the circumference and increases in the direction outside of a circle with larger radius.  The min/max's are only found on the circumference of the circle here.
Should it be possible using this theory to find the local max/min "inside" the pictured circle as well?
If the equation for the circle were modified so all points inside and on circumference were g(x,y) = c, then min/max's would be found inside as well correct?

ref:link
I'm using the following modified statements on this page:

Solve this system of equations:

$\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)$
$g(x,y) = c$

Evaluate $f(x,y)$ for all solutions to find $min$ and $max$ where $\nabla g \neq \vec 0$ at the points


If the constraint is inactive  at an extremum inside the circle than the gradient will be zero.

Gradient of which function? If the constraint is active does it mean $g(x,y)=c=0$? $x,y$ will be only on the circumference of the circle

Presumably you are trying to find an extremum of $f$. It either occurs with the constraint active $(g(x,y) = c$ or not. If not then the gradient of $f$ will be zero.

Yes I'm trying to find the absolute extremum of $f$.  I'm still unclear here.  If $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = g(x,y) = 0$ is the constraint in the system of equations to solve, then the constraint is active.  $(x,y)$ will be coordinates of the circle, and in this case the $\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y) = \vec v$ and $\vec v \neq \vec 0$.  In this case of the circle as the constraint, if there is an absolute extremum inside the circle it would be missed correct?  That's why I was asking about using 'if $(x^2 + y^2 <= 1)$ then $c$ else 0' $= g(x,y)$

Well, it depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to solve by hand, then (1) determine that extrema exist first (they do, since the closed ball is compact), (2) look for points where the gradient of $f$ is zero (may or may not be easy to do). If there are points on or inside the circle then check the values of these points, they will give you the $\max$ and $\min$. If not, then use Lagrange to find a constrained solution. This will, of course, be on the circle.
